# ec2 instances created by a launch template in auto-scaling group are not being registered with the target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

These are my alb configurations in case they are necessary.  Skip down to see the meat of the problem.

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.web.id
  lb_target_group_arn   = aws_lb_target_group.main.arn
}

resource "aws_lb" "main" {

  name               = "test-${var.env}-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"

  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elb.id]
  subnets         = [aws_subnet.main1.id, aws_subnet.main2.id]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project_name}-${var.env}-alb"
    Project     = var.project_name
    Environment = var.env
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "main" {
  name                 = "${var.project_name}-${var.env}-alb-tg"
  port                 = 80
  protocol             = "HTTP"
  vpc_id               = aws_vpc.main.id
  deregistration_delay = 30
  health_check {
    interval = 10
    matcher  = "200-299"
    path     = "/"
  }
 
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "main" {
 
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  port              = "443"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.main.arn
 
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main.arn
  }

}
```

============

I have an auto-scaling group created through terraform:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "web" {
  vpc_zone_identifier = [aws_subnet.main1.id]

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.web.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  min_size             = 1
  max_size             = 10

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

the launch template looks like this:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "web" {
  name_prefix            = "${var.project_name}-${var.env}-autoscale-web-"
  image_id               = var.web_ami
  instance_type          = "t3.small"
  key_name               = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.webserver.id]
}
```

if i use a launch configuration instead of a launch template, it works:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "web" {
  image_id      = var.web_ami
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  key_name = var.key_name
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.webserver.id]
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 8 # GB
    volume_type = "gp3"
  }
}
```

when using the launch configuration, the one line in the autoscaling_group is added:

```
launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.web.name
```

and the launch_template section is removed.

aws_launch_configuration is deprecated, so I'd like to use the launch_template.

Everything is working fine; the instance spins up and I can connect to it and it passes the health check.  The problem is that the EC2 instance doesn't automatically register with the target group.  When I manually register it with the target group, then everything works fine.

How can I get the EC2 instances that spin up with a launch template to automatically get added to the target group?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out aws_autoscaling_attachment is also deprecated, and I needed to add:

```
target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.main.arn]
```

to my aws_autoscaling_group.